# The Automorphism Group $\Gamma(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2}):\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial if $n$ is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

The full question is: Given a group $F_n=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n]{2})$ then prove that:

- (A) If $n$ is odd then $\Gamma(F_n:\mathbb{Q})$={$\rm{id}$} and
- (B) If $n$ is even then $\Gamma(F_n:\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z_2}$

I am confused as to how to find either, I know that $F_n:\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-normal extension. We were given the hint:

"For any $\tau\in\rm{Aut}_\mathbb{Q}(F_n)$ we must have that $\tau(\sqrt[n]{2})\in F_n\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is again a real $n$-th root of 2"

Comment: The given hint is pretty good. Can you prove that what it says is true? And what's stopping you from using it?

Comment: It's not a Galois group if the extension isn't Galois! (This is worth emphasizing, because it means the fundamental theorem of Galois theory doesn't hold.) Just say "automorphism group."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I will reword the title! My notes were not particularly in-depth when it came to nomenclature.

Comment: @Arthur I had a bit of a mental block with how it applied, from the answers I now see how useful it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $\mathbb Q$-automorphisms of $F_n$ are completely determined by where they send $\sqrt[n]2$, and they must send it to another $n$-th root of $2$. But if $n$ is odd, then no other $n$-th root of $2$ is in $F_n$, and if $n$ is even, then only one other $n$-th root of $2$ is in $F_n$ (you might need to prove these facts beforehand). So there are only one/two possible $\mathbb Q$-automorphisms.

Comment: Any advice on how to show there is no other root of 2 in $F_{n}$ if $n$ is odd? Surely we still have that $-\sqrt[n]{2}\in F_{n}$ even if that isn't the solution to the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ as $-1\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: $(-\sqrt[n]2)^n=-2\neq2$ for odd $n$.

Comment: I understand that, perhaps my definition of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[n](2)$ is wrong, I was lead to believe it is the group with set of form $\{a+b(\sqrt[n](2) \mid a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Comment: Yes, your definition is wrong. There are multiple possible definitions. The most conceptually clear one is that $K(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing both $K$ as a subfield and $\alpha$ as an element. If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $K$ with minimal polynomial of degree $n$, then this field is given by $\{c_0\alpha^0+c_1\alpha^1+\dots+c_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}~\vert~c_i\in K\}$. In the special case where $\alpha=\sqrt d$, where $d\in K$ is not a square, this happens to be $\{a+b\sqrt d~\vert~a,b\in K\}$, but that's just a special case.

Answer (score 0):

By Eisenstein's criterion, we know that $X^n-2$ is always irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. Hence $m(\sqrt[n]{2},\Bbb Q) = X^n-2$ and the roots of this polynomial are of the form $\xi_n^j\sqrt[n]{2}$ with $\xi_n$ an $n$-th primitive root and $1 \leq j \leq n$.

As you note, a morphism $\sigma \colon F_n/\Bbb Q \to \overline{\Bbb Q}$ will be determined by the image of $\sqrt[n]{2}$ in $\Bbb Q$ and, by the previous remark, this ought to be an element of the form $\xi_n^j \sqrt[n]{2}$. But if we want $\mathsf{im} \ \sigma$ to be in $\Bbb R$, can't we say something about $n$ and $j$?

> We need to have $\xi_n^j \in \Bbb R$. But a real root of unity is either $-1$ of $1$. Thus the options are $j = n, \xi_j^n = 1$ and $n \in 2\Bbb Z, j = n/2, \xi_n^j = -1$. When $n$ is even, both options can happen, hence the Galois group is cyclic generated by $\sigma$ such that $\sqrt[n]{2} \mapsto - \sqrt[n]{2}$. When $n$ is odd, the first case is the only one possible, thus every automorphism fixes $\sqrt[n]{2}$... but this means they were the identity to begin with.